# Предложение со слово кверху, книзу, вначале, вбок, наверх, совсем.

Tags: предложение

Comment: Да. 
Второй вопрос - как исправить свой вопрос...?
Я первый день на этом сайте.

Comment: Если Вам нужно составить предложения с этими словами, то здесь это не делается, так как считается выполнением домашнего задания. К примеру, вам могут ответить на вопрос, почему эти слова пишутся слитно и имеют ли они варианты с раздельным написанием. В любом случае, вы должны четко сформулировать свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Что вам конкретно нужно -  предложения, где встречаются эти наречия? Я вас правильно понял? Вот примеры: 1)"Пошли ***вбок,*** потом в другой — лавируем". И. А. Гончаров.2) Мы выбрались из подвала ***наверх.***(Толковый словарь Ушакова). 3) "На тебе (роще) не видно ни листка, и мерзнешь ты совсем нагая. Крылов. «Запел, да только лишь совсем особым складом". Крылов. Остальные примеры Вы можете найти в словарях на Академике. Достаточно ввести нужное вам слово - и словарь сразу принесет это слово с примерами. Вот ссылка. http://dic.academic.ru/ А исправить ваш вопрос вы можете нажав на  пункт "править", который находится прямо под вопросом.